# Oracle Min & Max Date

Tags: oracle10g

I would like to get max date and min date value from single column. Please help.

I have 6 fields. All are same but only difference is with date, I need to get max and min out of it. Kindly Help

Answer (score 1):

```
select min(date_col) as min, 
       max(date_col) as max
from your_table
```